# In what situations is the animation warmup reset? (iOS)

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/shader
says:

> On iOS, “first run” means that the user might see jank when an
> animation first occurs **every time the user opens the app from scratch**.

But in my device (iPhone 5S)

*First open after app install

*First open after device boot

Not every opening from scratch.

Comment: So you're getting jank on your device ?

Comment: Yes, related with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485696/flutter-ios-animations-are-janky-on-first-run